# how to process a HTTP stream with Dart

Tags: dart

cross posted from dartisans G+ where I got no response so far:

Q: how to do (async) simultaneous stream downloads.

Hi, I'm still learning Dart and, for training,  I'd like to create a web page from which I can fetch datas from 1 to 10 URLs that are HTTP streams of binary data. Once I got a chunk of data from each streams , simultaneously, I then perform a computation and proceed to next chunks and so on, ad lib. I need parallelism because the client has much more network bandwith than the servers.
Also I do not want to fully download each URL they're too big to fit in memory or even on local storage. Actually,  It's pretty similar to video streaming but it's not video data it's binary data and instead of displaying data I just do some computation and I do that on many streams at a time.

Can I do that with Dart and how ? do dart:io or dart:async have the classes I can use to do that ? do I need to use "webworkers" to spawn 1 to 10 simultaneous http requests ?

any pointers/advices/similar samples would be greatly appreciated.

tl;dr: how to process a HTTP stream of data chunk by chunk and how to parallelize this to process many streams at the same time.

Comment: hello. Ik it has been 7 years, but have  you got any results? Have been looking for stream consumption for some days, but have not found yet

Comment: hi. sorry no I gave up on Dart shortly after.